# How to apply an assumption to all nested tests in Junit5?

Tags: java, junit5

I have converted Junit4 suite to Junit5 nested classes:

```
class MadvocSuiteTest {
    @Nested
    class HelloActionTest extends HelloActionTestBase {}
    @Nested
    class SimpleTest extends SimpleTestBase {}
    ...
}
```

I must skip the suite for Java9 (since MultiRelease-Jars are not working in the expanded mode).

How can I do that for the whole suite i.e. all nested classes, so not to add `assumeTrue` to every single test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you encounter functionality needed in more than a single JUnit Jupiter test class, think of the new Extension Model. In your case, the [Conditional Test Execution](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-conditions) extension point.

Here is an example of what you might want to do by Mike Kobit. Define your own extension `DisabledOnJava9` like:

```
@ExtendWith(DisabledOnJava9Condition.class)
public @interface DisabledOnJava9 {}
```

And the handler like his `DisabledOnJava9Condition.java`. Now you may use your `DisabledOnJava9` annotation on any element you want to. This includes the entire test class or any nested class.

Find the source of all types by Mike here: https://github.com/mkobit/junit5-conditional-execution-extensions

Here is another example of implementing this extension point: https://blog.codefx.org/libraries/junit-5-conditions/

Comment: [Worked](https://github.com/oblac/jodd/tree/master/jodd-core/src/test/java/jodd/test). Adding assumptions also worked, but this is better.